# SQL Triggers and composite keys

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a trigger for a table, and I have the following statement:

```
UPDATE [dbo].ConsignmentTripBreakdown SET VehicleTypeID = CONVERT(bigint,LTRIM(RTRIM(VehicleType)))
WHERE [dbo].ConsignmentTripBreakdown.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)
```

Problem is, there is no 'ID' field on the ConsignmentTripBreakdown - instead there's a composite key on 3 fields. How would I rework the where clause for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  [dbo].ConsignmentTripBreakdown
SET
  VehicleTypeID = CONVERT(bigint,LTRIM(RTRIM(inserted.VehicleType)))
FROM
  [dbo].ConsignmentTripBreakdown
INNER JOIN
  inserted
    ON  inserted.pk_part1 = ConsignmentTripBreakdown.pk_part1
    AND inserted.pk_part2 = ConsignmentTripBreakdown.pk_part2
    AND inserted.pk_part3 = ConsignmentTripBreakdown.pk_part3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a join to the `inserted` table on all component columns of the composite key. For example:

```
UPDATE ctb
SET ctb.VehicleTypeID = CONVERT(bigint,LTRIM(RTRIM(VehicleType)))
FROM  [dbo].ConsignmentTripBreakdown ctb
INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.k1 = ctb.k1 and i.k2 = ctb.k2 and i.k3 = ctb.k3
```

Comment: VehicleType will potentially exist in both tables.  Need to be more specific.

Comment: I'm sure that it will *potentially* exist in both tables, yes ;)  But as the OP shows `x.id IN (inserted.id)` it seems more likely hat not to me, as I would have otherwise expected one or other field names to be `something_id`.  Not a guarantee, no, but enough that I'd want to play safe.